# Vee-Validate custom date validation

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I was wondering if there is anyway you can write a custom date validation using vee-validate plugin where the end date cannot be less than the start date? I have looked high and low, and there is nowhere I can find a definite answer to this.

If there is no way to implement this, then I can make do without it, however, right now what I have implemented in my template for my start date is:

```
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="form-control" v-model="startDate" v-validate="'required|date_format:DD-MM-YYYY'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('startDate') }">
    <label class="mb-0" for="startDate">Start Date</label>
        <span v-show="errors.has('startdate')" class="text-danger"><center>{{ errors.first('startdate') }}</center></span>
```

My script looks like this:

```
    export default {
    name: 'App',
    data: () => ({
        task: '',
        startDate: '',
        startTime: '',
        endDate: '',
        endTime: '',
        description: 'test'
    }),
    methods: {
        validateBeforeSubmit() {
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                alert('Form Submitted!');
                return;
                }

                alert('Correct them errors!');
            });
        }
    }

};
```

But there is no validation that is showing up. I think I am missing something in my script but I am not sure how to implement the date into there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

First, it's maybe some typo error but in your template you use `startDate` and `startdate` lowercased.

Then, to answer your question, it's possible to define a **[custom validator](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/custom-rules.html)** with a date comparison with vee-validate.

As your chosen date format "DD-MM-YYYY" is not a valid javascript Date format, the string dates need to be rewritten into a valid format to make it work.

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      startDate: '',
      endDate: '',
    }
  },
  created() {
    let self = this
    this.$validator.extend('earlier', {
      getMessage(field, val) {
        return 'must be earlier than startDate'
      },
      validate(value, field) {
        let startParts = self.startDate.split('-')
        let endParts = value.split('-')
        let start = new Date(startParts[2], startParts[1] -1, startParts[0]) // month is 0-based
        let end = new Date(endParts[2], endParts[1] -1, endParts[0])

        return end > start
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    validateBeforeSubmit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          alert('Form Submitted!');
          return;
        }
        alert('Correct them errors!');
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.is-danger, .text-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@2.0.0-rc.19/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="startDate" v-model="startDate"v-validate="'required|date_format:DD-MM-YYYY'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('startDate') }">
    <label class="mb-0" for="startDate">Start Date</label>
    <span v-show="errors.has('startDate')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('startDate') }}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="endDate" v-model="endDate" v-validate="'required|date_format:DD-MM-YYYY|earlier'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('endDate') }">
    <label class="mb-0" for="endDate">End Date</label>
    <span v-show="errors.has('endDate')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('endDate') }}</span>  
  </div>

  <button @click="validateBeforeSubmit">Save</button>
</div>
```

*Note*: i put the custom validator inside the created hook for the example but you can put it inside any file you want in your projet. Just import it correctly as the documentation recommends.

Comment: Thank you for the help! There is just one problem in the code you provided; even after I put in an end date greater than the start date, I still get an error message.

Comment: @BansariPatel yes you are right, it's because "DD-MM-YYYY" is not a valid javascript Date format. The string dates need to be rewrite in a valid format to make it work. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Sovalina, can you have a look at a vee-validate related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444033/vue-js-bootstrapvue-veevalidate-cannot-validate-datepicker ?